# In App Billing Read From Cache

Tags: android, caching, in-app-billing

I have recently released my app on Google play. The app contains a premium version, so if purchased, the Premium-user gets extra features.

To check whether a user is premium or not, I have implemented a test. I have followed the example in TrivialDrive from the Android samples. The thing is that I have noticed that sometimes it takes a while before the app detects that a user is a Premium user. I have twice seen on my friends phone that it does not detect the premium status until you try to open the premium feature again after a while.

I have started to suspect that it has something to do with the connection to the server that takes time. I thought it was cache automatically, but now I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    MainActivity.showToast("onResume");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY1);
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY2);
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY3);
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY4);
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY5);
    sb.append(BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY6);
    final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = sb.toString();
    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    //  Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(false);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    // Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            //  Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                MainActivity.showToast("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // Important: Dynamically register for broadcast messages about updated purchases.
            // We register the receiver here instead of as a <receiver> in the Manifest
            // because we always call getPurchases() at startup, so therefore we can ignore
            // any broadcasts sent while the app isn't running.
            // Note: registering this listener in an Activity is a bad idea, but is done here
            // because this is a SAMPLE. Regardless, the receiver must be registered after
            // IabHelper is setup, but before first call to getPurchases().
            mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(SkeetStatistic.this);
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.

            ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
            list_items.add(SKU_PREMIUM);

            // Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, list_items, mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}
```

mGotInventoryListener:

```
     // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
      //  Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
         //   Log.d(TAG,"Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

     //   Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
    /*
     * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
     * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
     * verifyDeveloperPayload().
     */

    // Do we have the premium upgrade?
    Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
    mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
    if (mIsPremium){
     //   System.out.println("Premium");
       MainActivity.showToast("Premium");
    }
    if (!mIsPremium){
        MainActivity.showToast("Not Premium");
    }
  //  Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));

    setWaitScreen(false);
  //  Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
}
};
```

When I look in the IabHelper class, it seems that they call

```
mService.getPurchase().
```

As I have understood it from the documentation, that should read it from cache, but I might be wrong.

Any ideas how to make it more robust are appreciated. I don't really like that some Premium users get the choice to upgrade when they already have.

Regards
Erik

Answer (score 0):

To avoid (reduce) situations when user can launch purchase flow on already owned products you need to folow next recomendations:

1. Use local cache or your own remote server to load initialize state for activity. In [TrivialDrive](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) this looks like code below:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // load game data
       loadData();
       mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
       mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
           // listener implementation
       }
       //...
   }

   void loadData() {
       SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
       mTank = sp.getInt("tank", 2);
       Log.d(TAG, "Loaded data: tank = " + String.valueOf(mTank));
   }
   ```
2. Check owned purchases before show products list to user
3. In case of user already have product, just skeep purchase flow and show only congrantulations for user. Like this: "Thanks for upgrade to PREMIUM version!"